# Firebug: omits output in certain cases

Tags: javascript, firebug

When i run this bit of code in Firebug:

```
 var s ="test";
 var S=new String(s);
 S.len=4;
 var t = S.len;
 console.log(t);
 typeof(S);
 S;
```

It totally omits the output for `typeof(S);`
But if I do:

```
  var s ="test";
  var S=new String(s);
  S.len=4;
  var t = S.len;
  console.log(t);
  console.log(typeof(S));
  S;
```

It does just right, what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug's log gives you the result of the *last* expression (as a debug feature), not *each* expression. Anything passing `console.log()` will of course turn up, and you'll see this if you do

```
console.log(typeof (S));
```

But it throws in the return value of the last expression and the end, always, but not the preceding ones.

Thus the sequence:

```
S;
typeof (S);
```

Will yield the return value of `typeof (S);` and nothing else and the sequence:

```
typeof (S);
S;
```

Will yield the return value if `S` (which is just `S`). Since the results aren't stored anywhere in your code it just runs the expression and does away with the result, **except** in the last expression of any of the above sequences, where *Firebug* shows you what the result was. This is to facilitate say running a jQuery expression or the like.

Comment: but it shows all the results in the last 2 cases..is outputting functions and objects any different?

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it clearer. If you want output in the log, you should *always* use `console.log()` (mind though, that IE does not support it and will throw an exception).